# Converting a String with Length of Time into Different DataType

Tags: sql, sql-server, types, sqldatatypes, string-conversion

I am working in sql server and have been provided with a file that has a column for "Duration" which contains string type values of length of time formatted HH:MM:SS.

Example:

```
Duration:
00:01:34, 
00:25:20, 
01:01:53
```

I am trying to figure out how to convert those strings into a data type I can use to calculate things like "average duration" and "total duration" etc. which I obviously can't run on a string.

I have formatted all of the values the same way and have attempted to use CAST and CONVERT to change the data type to time.

My query will start to run and convert a few thousand rows but then error out with the following error message:

Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Attempting CAST:

```
SELECT CAST(Duration as time)
FROM TABLE
```

Attempting CONVERT:

```
SELECT CONVERT(time, Duration)
FROM TABLE
```

The conversion starts on my files and when I look at the results tab the results look as expected, with HH:MM:SS.nnnnnnn format but then the query errors out after a few thousand rows.

Am I just going about this in the completely wrong way? The only other thing I can think of is maybe breaking up the string, calculating the length of time and storing it in seconds and then recalculating the duration after running any aggregation calculations. I was hoping there was a more straight forward way to get there though.

Comment: Sounds like you have some values that can't be converted. Use TRY_CONVERT instead. Then it will return NULL when the string is not valid.

Answer (score 2):

You have data that doesn't match.  You can just use `TRY_CAST()` or `TRY_CONVERT()` if you don't care about the non-matches (that is, if values that do not look like a time value are converted to `NULL`).

If you want to find the offending values:

```
SELECT Duration
FROM TABLE
WHERE TRY_CAST(Duration as time) IS NULL AND Duration IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thank you! When I looked for the values that didn't match all of the results had over 23 in the hours position.

Comment: @Jessie . . . That is not a valid time in SQL Server.  If you want, you can ask another question about how to handle them.